# Passing Hash as Instance Variable in Get Method In Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm creating a metro application for a project. I'm attempting to pass a hash containing the options that a user can select as the key and the url it will redirect to as the value. When I do, sinatra reports:

no implicit conversion of Array into String

Which is strange, because I do not have an array so far in my application. I have tried commenting out the embedded ruby in the index.erb file, but that didn't help. The application is as follows:

```
require "sinatra"
require "sinatra/reloader"

red = {
    "Woodley Park" => '/woodley_park',
    "Dupont Circle" => '/dupont_circle',
    "Farragut North" => '/farragut_north',
    "Metro Center" => '/metro_center',
    "Union Station" => '/union_station'
}

turquoise = {
    "Crystal City" => '/crystal_city',
    "Metro Center" => '/metro_center',
    "Shaw-Howard" => '/shaw_howard',
    "Beltwater" => '/beltwater'
}

orange = {
    "Farragut West" => '/farragut_west',
    "McPherson" => '/mcpherson',
    "Metro Center" => '/metro_center',
    "Federal Triangle" => '/federal_triangle',
    "Smithsonsian" => '/smithsonsian',
    "L'efant Plaza" => '/lefant_planza'
}

lines = {
    "Red" => "/red_line",
    "Turquoise" => "/turquoise_line",
    "Orange" => "/orange_line"
}

get '/' do
    @header = "Welcome to the D.C. Metro! Which line will you be starting at?"
    @options = lines
end
```

And the index.erb looks like this. Again, commenting out the relevant lines did not change the results. Thanks in advance!

```
<h2><%= @header %></h2>

<% @options.each do |name, link| %>
<a href=<%= link %>><%= name %></a>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please include the entire stack trace. You're saying this happen when you hit `/`?

Comment: "Internal Server Error

no implicit conversion of Array into String"

Is the entire error message. It does happen when I hit / .

Any idea what it might be?

Comment: Hey, it turns out that I was just missing the "erb :index" line in the get method. Thanks for the help!